# /etc/network/interfaces and ifup/ifdown still present. Why?

Tags: networking, netplan

**netplan** is now the default network *configurator* on **18.04**

- But on a freshly installed 18.04 system, I am still finding `/etc/network` stuff with `interfaces` file and other directories.
- the ifup/ifdown utilities are still installed

Why ?
It seems the ifupdown package is a dependance of pppoeconf (?).
There is even a systemd service called networking that calls ifquery/ifup/ifdown ???

Comment: One reason I can think of is for *backwards compatibility*. Like why is `cpio` still there?  Or why is `ifconfig` or `egrep`?

Comment: The reason, I'm guessing, is that netplan hands off control to systemd , and that inturn uses the ifup/ifdown stuff. At least that's my impression from reading   https://git.launchpad.net/netplan/tree/doc/netplan.md?_ga=2.45833252.1635931741.1525818127-344530470.1455200756   Also perhaps some scripts use it  https://git.launchpad.net/netplan/tree/doc/netplan.md?_ga=2.45833252.1635931741.1525818127-344530470.1455200756

Comment: netplan is used to configure systemd-networkd (which has already its configuration file but never mind) or hand it to network-manager. I don't think networkd use ifupdown. I just run `sudo apt remove ifupdown` without problem. Just waiting to see if something will break at next boot ;-)

Comment: @solsTiCe I see you like to live dangerously :)

Comment: "Look ma, no hands !".  ;-) .Well calculated risk. Nothing bad happeneded.  It's just fear that let ubuntu dev accumulate  dust. I can tell you I have removed also rsyslog. Using systemd-journald in persistent mode.

Answer (score 1):

*ifupdown* is still being pulled in by *pppoeconf*; which may get installed on desktops (on servers, there should be no trace of *ifupdown*).

There is no use for *ifupdown* if you don't use *pppoeconf*, both can be safely removed. They were still installed automatically because some users may need *pppoeconf* to successfully get online and get additional packages.

If you upgrade from 16.04 or from 17.10, you will also have ifupdown remain on the system, since we can't safely migrate all configurations. It's better to leave ~400k around on the system (ifupdown + pppoeconf + any config they have) than to remove them and risk breaking things on upgrade.

/etc/network/interfaces is also left behind so we can point users to netplan, given the large number of docs that will be left around mentioning ifupdown here and there on the Internet.